# How to turn thin thread into thick thread for hand embroidery

Tags: sewing, thread

[This video](https://youtu.be/_chnvLD5DUw?t=95) explains how to turn thin thread into thick thread.

This is suitable for making friendship bracelets, but it's not scalable to embroidering an 8-foot shawl, for instance. Plus, this shawl will utilize 3 to 4 (5 maximum) distinct colors of thread.

Can anyone please tell me how I can turn thin thread into thick thread?
(Embroidery floss and even sock yarn have jaw-dropping prices!)

Comment: It is better if you transcribe the text here, so it can be read. Maybe attach some pictures. The video can be removed, and then your question will no longer have the proper details. Additionally, videos are disabled on many networks, and therefore not viewable.

Comment: 40 spools of embroidery thread on Amazon is $26. 50 skeins of embroidery floss on Amazon is $7. 100 skeins is $7.50. I don't know where you're looking, but embroidery floss is always significantly cheaper than embroidery thread; just use the proper material for the job.

Comment: Don't forget that if you want (say) 3x thicker you'll need 3x the length - so you need to take that into account when comparing prices, unless you plan on never finishing a reel

Comment: All that video showed was to chain the thread which can be done with any thread or yarn.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a thread type or color you must use...double or triple the thread in the needle. If you had something or someone that could ply the threads (spin them together) you'd have the best results.

Good Luck.